# Usage of twice-twice-broken-glass

Tags: adverbs

Glass has been broken twice and there exists twice-broken glass twice. Is twice-twice-broken glass a proper expression?

Comment: I'm curious where you've ever seen twice-twice broken glass used, and what you think it means.

Comment: I think I should say double-broken.

Comment: I'm afraid one word has meaning twice and double in my language...

Comment: Are you describing glass that has been broken two separate times? If so,*twice-broken glass* works. However, you would need a reason to say this -- can you see two different kinds of breaks? Be aware that a phrase like *twice-broken glass* is usually only used in poetry.